# Control Knob Shape

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create this shape of the control knob, but I'm confused how to go on about. I'm starting off with the cylinder mesh, but I cannot figure out how to get the rounded curves and bend which this control knob makes. Could someone please  give me some insight how to achieve this shape.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Start with a 7 sided cylinder then bevel the edges with a profile lower than 0.5

Comment: Create a Bezier Circle, model the profile to your requirement and then Extrude it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by adding a cylinder with 7 vertices.

[image]

Switch to edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd> and select the 7 vertical edges of the cylinder.

[image]

Bevel the selected edges either by using the *Bevel* tool or by using the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. Press the mouse button and drag until you have the desired beveling or adjust the width option in the last operation panel. You can use <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> for a top down view.

[image]

Use the *Loop Cut* tool or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> while pointing with the mouse between the beveled areas. This will add loop cuts that we can indent slightly to match the reference image. Repeat this until all areas in between have the loop cuts.

[image]
[image]

Select the created loop cuts and scale them along the X and Y axis (<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>).

[image]

Select the vertical edges of the beveling and use the *Offset Edge Loop Cut* to add supporting edge loops.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Close the top (and bottom) cap of the cylinder by selecting the edge loop, extruding (<kbd>E</kbd>), scaling inwards (<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) and filling the cap (<kbd>F</kbd>).

[image]

Add a bevel for the transition to the cap.

[image]

Finally set shading to smooth and add a subdivision modifier.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your helpful insight.

Answer (score 3):

Use your image as background, create a 14 vertices circle, scale half of its vertices, select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel, extrude up, close the top, bevel the edge.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for contributing to my question.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a 7 sided cylinder then bevel the vertical edges with a profile lower than 0.5 in the dialog box. By tweaking the number of sides and the the bevel size too you should get what you need.